# Remove duplicated notes in Evernote

Tags: evernote

I ended up importing hunderds of notes that already were in the database.

Anyone knows how to automaticly Evernote Remove duplicated Notes?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, although not the same quantity.

Currently the Evernote Knowledge-base says that it is not possible to automatically find and remove duplicates. Their suggestion is:

> ... follow these steps to manually remove many of your duplicate notes:
>
> 1. In your Evernote client application on Windows or OS X, change the
>      view to List View.
> 2. Click All Notes.
> 3. Sort the notes alphabetically by
>      title by clicking the Title heading above the note list.
>
> From here, you can look at the note titles and identify and remove duplicate notes with relative ease.

Taken from https://evernote.com/contact/support/kb/#!/article/23193597  (Dec 2014)

Which is what I did, but I can imagine this is not a great option if you have a large number of duplicates. (*Relative ease* being a subjective phrase.)